# Restrict functions to namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I am building some sort of a neural network library. As I have never built any libraries before, I have some questions concerning the style.
In my project there are for example following classes:

```
NeuralNetwork, Layer, Util
```

all in one namespace. Now, `Layer` and `Util` need to have some public functions as they will be called in `NeuralNetwork`. But since `NeuralNetwork` is the only class that should be accessible for 'the rest of the world' (and btw. it doesn't make any sense to create a single `Layer` object).

So is there some way I could only use those functions in other classes in that namespace? Or is there a more elegant approach? I thought of extending the class and making only private functions but that wouldn't make any sense and would make the code uglier as the main class does not derive from the others but rather makes use of them.

Comment: The best way to learn what production quality libraries do, is to examine them.

Comment: Is what I am talking about even a problem you should address? Or do you just live with it and hope that nobody thinks of doing strange things with it.

Comment: @po0l: If you define `Util` in `Util.h`, and you only use `Util.h` in `NeuralNetwork.cpp` and not `NeuralNetwork.h`, you do not need to distribute `Util.h` to your users. And even if you provide the whole source, it's not unusual to only put public headers in `include/` and to keep implementation-internal headers in `src/`.

Comment: You can't stop people doing something they shouldn't. So as the saying goes, protect them from Murphy, not Machiavelli. Make it so they can't write broken code by accident. But don't worry about any intentions they may have to shoot themselves in the foot. To give an example, the boost library places implementation details into an inner `boost::detail` namespace. Sure, people can access it if they feel courageous. But responsible adults won't get hurt by anything in there.

Comment: @po0l: Yes, live with it and hope. But in addition to hoping, write clear documentation which tells clients to use only those classes which are meant to be exposed, and put the internal classes into their own namespace with a descriptive name, like `detail` or `implementation`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the *anonymous namespace*. A bit weird name, I admit.

Basically, in the following code, `foo` is *only* available to the rest of the .cpp file:

```
namespace {
  class Foo { public: Foo(int) {} } ; 
}
```

Behind the scenes, the compiler will create a unique name, something that cannot clash with any other namespace - not even the anonymous namespaces of other libraries! You don't care about that hidden name. In your .cpp file, you can just use `Foo` directly.

Comment: and the entire library must be in one .cpp file ?

Comment: @KjellGunnar: No, but note that each .cpp file in the library has its own anonymous namespace.